# How do I treat aluminium oxidation on body panels?

Tags: paint, body-work, aluminum

Like most of us I have dealt with steel rust on many occasions, but how should I deal with aluminium corrosion bubbles under the paint?

I have just bought my first aluminium car, which are becoming a lot more common now. 
The bonnet has a few stone chips which have started to bubble.

On a steel car one would sand back, use a rust treatment (krust for example) and then fill / paint.

But How should I "Kill" the aluminium oxidation?

Answer (score 1):

Same as steel panels, only if you use wire disc on angle grinder, use a softer brush. Everything else the same.

Comment: but rust-converters are made for steel, not ally

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Wire brush -> fill + paint. If you're expecting to convert the alumina back to aluminum you're not going to find a reasonable chemical treatment to do that. You just have to remove it then either hide or fill any resulting pits.

Comment: Sorry, didn't really think of rust converters.. I just never used them, I always grind everything physically out and buy a high quality primer.